# How to change encryption for SSHD in Fedora Server 29?

Tags: fedora, encryption, sshd

CRYPTO_POLICY field is empty and I do not know where to start.

I only read about LEGACY, DEFAULT and FUTURE options (what is not clear for me absolutely how it is relates to SSHD).

```
# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# System-wide Crypto policy:
# This system is following system-wide crypto policy. The changes to
# Ciphers, MACs, KexAlgoritms and GSSAPIKexAlgorithsm will not have any
# effect here. They will be overridden by command-line options passed on
# the server start up.
# To opt out, uncomment a line with redefinition of  CRYPTO_POLICY=
# variable in  /etc/sysconfig/sshd  to overwrite the policy.
# For more information, see manual page for update-crypto-policies(8).
```

The main idea is to change default encryption to fast algorithm (or disable it). It is local machine for tests, so only performance is matter.

Comment: First, try doing what the comment tells you to do.

Comment: I reverted my original description of the problem and updated it. Hopefully it will have a different meaning now.

Comment: Did you edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` as it told you to do?

Comment: # System-wide crypto policy:
# To opt-out, uncomment the following line
# CRYPTO_POLICY=
And what will happen if this line is uncommented? How will it help to configure SSHD?

Comment: As it says, you will then be able to use the sshd options.

Comment: Hmm, sounds correct. I will check. Thanks Michael.